# SharePoint-specific WebPart-class (instead of System.Web.UI)

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2013

I just recently started using SharePoint 2013. I created the project using the built-in tools (Office Developer add-ons) as a SharePoint project.

I am porting a SharePoint 2010 project with a few webpart more or less file-by-file. The old webparts made use of the `WebPart` class found in `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart`. According to MSDN, this should also exist in SharePoint 2013. However, it is NOT present (I get compiler errors).

My question is: Which DLL / `using` directive am I missing?

I tried using `using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages` (and inheriting from `WebPart`), but it still comes up as an error (`using` works fine though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had set up my project to be sandboxed, which disables some features including this specific WebPart-type. Re-creating the project as a non-sandboxed project made it work.